# TensorFlow: Convert GRUCell weights from compat.v1 to tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to convert a saved model in tensorflow 1 to tensorflow 2. I am migrating the code to tensorflow 2, as higlighted [in tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate). However, I would like to simply update my `model_weights.ckpt` to **tensorflow 2**. Some weights (`Linear`, `Embdedding`) have a similar shape to **tensorflow 2** syntax, but I am struggling to transform the weights from my `GRUCell`.

### How to convert the `GRUCell` weights from `compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell` to `keras.layers.GRUCell` ?

The `GRUCell` has four weights:

- `gru_cell/gates/kernel:0` of shape `(S + H, 2 x H)`,
- `gru_cell/gates/bias:0` of shape `(2 x H, )`,
- `gru_cell/candidate/kernel:0` of shape `(S + H, H)`,
- `gru_cell/candidate/bias:0` of shape `(H, )`

I would like to have weights with a similar shape to **tensoflow 2** API (or PyTorch API), i.e. a `GRUCell` with the following weights:

- `gru_cell/kernel:0` of shape `(S, 3 x H)`
- `gru_cell/recurrent_kernel:0` of shape `(H, 3 x H)`
- `gru_cell/bias:0` of shape `(2, 3 x H)`

### To illustrate, you can reproduce these results:

#### 1. `GRUCell` with **tensorflow 1** API

```py
import tensorflow as tf

SEQ_LENGTH = 4
HIDDEN_SIZE = 512
BATCH_SIZE = 1
inputs = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, SEQ_LENGTH])

# GRU cell
gru = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(HIDDEN_SIZE)
# Hidden state
state = gru.zero_state(BATCH_SIZE, tf.float32)
# Forward
output, state = gru(inputs, state)

for weight in gru.weights:
    print(weight.name, weight.shape)
```

Output:

```
gru_cell/gates/kernel:0 (516, 1024)
gru_cell/gates/bias:0 (1024,)
gru_cell/candidate/kernel:0 (516, 512)
gru_cell/candidate/bias:0 (512,)
```

#### 2. `GRUCell` with **tensorflow 2** API

```py
import tensorflow as tf

SEQ_LENGTH = 4
HIDDEN_SIZE = 512
BATCH_SIZE = 1
inputs = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE , SEQ_LENGTH])

# GRU cell
gru = tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(HIDDEN_SIZE)
# Hidden state
state = tf.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE), dtype=tf.float32)
# Forward
output, state = gru(inputs, state)

# Display the weigths
for weight in gru.weights:
    print(weight.name, weight.shape)
```

Output:

```
gru_cell/kernel:0 (4, 1536)
gru_cell/recurrent_kernel:0 (512, 1536)
gru_cell/bias:0 (2, 1536)
```

### Note

- I tried [`_convert_rnn_weights` tensorflow function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c52ee536c045186476450cf76461d47fb2667e7d/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py#L404-L568) to convert the desired weights. It works but only for `CuDNN` weights, so I can't use it in my case.

Comment: There are some workarounds mentioned for checkpoint compatibility [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#checkpoint_compatibility), if you haven't tried please take a look and use these workarounds and lets see the result. Thanks

Comment: This does not answer the problem. The [checkpoint converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tools/checkpoint_converter.py) highlighted works for `DNN`, `Linear` or `Combined` estimator. It does not support complex models (ex GAN and others). However, if I could just manually convert `GRUCell` weights to `keras` syntax, it will solve my problem as I would be able to load the checkpoint / model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of community providing solution here though it is presented in [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44948#issuecomment-735047539).

In short, the weights between `compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell` and `keras.layers.GRUCell` are not compatible between each other. We don't have a function to convert between them, and if you really want to do it, you will need to do it manually.

Math wise, if you have the numpy value of the v1 weights, the formula are:

B = batch_size

H = state_size

1. all_kernel = np.concat([gru_cell/gates/kernel, gru_cell/candidate/kernel], axis=1) # shape (B+H, 3 * H)
2. kernel = all_kernel[:B] # shape(B, 3 * H)
3. recurrent_kernel = all_kernel[B:] # shape (H, 3 * H)
4. bias = np.concat([gru_cell/gates/bias, gru_cell/candidate/bias], axis=0) # shape (B, 3 * H)
5. zero_bias = np.zeros([B, 3 * H])
6. bias = np.concat([bias, zero_bias], axis=0)

Comment: Is the shape of the bias a typo? `[3 * H, ]` without `B`.